# How to remember the prior page before accessing subsequent pages across frame

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I get two frames, says A and B. Clicking a link in A will trigger page in B changing from **URL_A** to URL_B.

**How do I remember URL_A**, so that when users click cancel button in URL_B, they can go back to **URL_A**?

how do I get mainFrame's URL in fraTopMenu?

```
<frameset rows="60,*" cols="*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">  
  <frame src="/Common/Manager/TopMenu.aspx" name="fraTopMenu" 
    scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" id="fraTopMenu" title="" />  
  <frameset rows="*" cols="185,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="no" border="0">  
    <frame src="/Common/Manager/LeftMenu.aspx" name="leftFrame" id="leftFrame" 
      title="" />  
    <frame src="<%= MainUrl %>" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" />
  </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Clicking a link in frame A will cause frame B's URL to change to URL_B from URL_A

Change the frame B's URL to `URL_B?back_url=URL_A` instead. Now you can read URL_A from the `document.location.search.split[1]`

You can get the frame's url using `top.frames[2].window.location.href`

Comment: Hi, how do I know URL_A in frame B from frame A?

Comment: It'll be in `document.getElementById(id-of-frame-B).src`

Comment: In frame A, don't I need to specifiy "top".document.getElementById(id-of-frame-B).src

Comment: If the frames aren't nested, you can use `top.frames["frame-name"].src`

Comment: otherwise you'll need to go `top.frames["outerframe"].frames["innerframe"].so-on.src`

Comment: Hi, how do I get mainFrame's URL in fraTopMenu?

<frameset rows="60,*" cols="*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
      <frame src="/Common/Manager/TopMenu.aspx"  name="fraTopMenu" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" id="fraTopMenu" title="" />
      <frameset rows="*" cols="185,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="no" border="0">
        <frame src="/Common/Manager/LeftMenu.aspx" name="leftFrame" id="leftFrame" title="" />
        <frame src="<%= MainUrl %>" name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" />
      </frameset>
    </frameset>

Comment: `top.frames[2].window.location.href` @Ricky

Answer (score 0):

The Http Referer might be your best bet.  It is (at best) an unreliable mechanism to use as it is sent from the browser and is just as often blank.